# Sampling n= 2000 from a Dask Dataframe of len 18000 generates error Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'

Tags: python, dask

I have a dask dataframe created from a csv file and `len(daskdf)` returns 18000 but when I `ddSample = daskdf.sample(2000)` I get the error

```
ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'
```

Can I sample without replacement if the dataframe is larger than the sample size?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The sample method only supports the `frac=` keyword argument.  See the [API documentation](http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.sample)

The error that you're getting is from Pandas, not Dask.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1]})
In [3]: df.sample(frac=2000, replace=False)
ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'
```

#### Solution 1

As the Pandas error suggests, consider sampling *with replacement*

```
In [4]: df.sample(frac=2, replace=True)
Out[4]: 
   x
0  1
0  1

In [5]: import dask.dataframe as dd
In [6]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
In [7]: ddf.sample(frac=2, replace=True).compute()
Out[7]: 
   x
0  1
0  1
```

#### Solution 2

This may help someone..

I found this from some place and cannot remember where.

This will show you the results correctly without error. (This is for pandas, and I don't know about dask).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'b': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3]})

# this is fixed number, will be error when data in group is less than sample size
df.groupby('b').apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, n=1)

# this is flexible with min, no error, will return 3 or less than that
df.groupby(['b'], as_index=False, group_keys=False
          ).apply(
            lambda x: x.sample(min(3, len(x)))
        )
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm still having trouble understanding it `sampledf = df.sample(frac=2000)` still generates the error if I `sampledf.head()`

Comment: Yes, pandas can't generate a larger sample than the population.  Frac needs to be less than one, like `df.sample(frac=0.10)`.  Alternatively perhaps you want to set `replace=True`?

Comment: is there anyway i want to use `n=5` and `replace=False`, and pandas should automatically choose random sample with a `max limit of 5`. if dataframe has only 1 record, then just show 1 record instead of 5. I don't want to use replace=True to repeat the record 5 times. I don't want repeats. I don't want to use frac either, as i know i don't want more than 5.

Comment: @ihightower I am facing same problem. If you found solution can you please share

Comment: @10sha25 hi i have added my answer further below.. and added as solution 2 above. hope this helps.

Comment: ```frac``` argument should be given a value between 0 to 1. The answer is best modified as a fraction to get the size you want. perhaps like 2000/18000.

Answer (score 1):

I found this from some place and cannot remember where.

This will show you the results correctly without error. (This is for pandas, and I don't know about dask).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'b': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3]})

# this is fixed number, will be error when data in group is less than sample size
df.groupby('b').apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, n=1)

# this is flexible with min, no error, will return 3 or less than that
df.groupby(['b'], as_index=False, group_keys=False
          ).apply(
            lambda x: x.sample(min(3, len(x)))
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `sample` method, change parameter `replace` as `True`.

```
df.sample(samples, replace=True)
```

It is indicated, that the size of DataFrame is larger than the number of samples they need. So this is a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the point is that he wants to extract a sample of rows from the original dataframe, so imho I think you should specify `axis=0` to sample from rows.